# , How can IntelliJ support some features which TypeScript compiler does not support?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, liskov-substitution-principle

Like `literal type` refactor and goto implementation returns different results between Vscode and IntelliJ. Do IntelliJ uses LSP to communicate with tsc or they just implements another tsc?

Comment: Do you mean vscode or the ts compiler?

Comment: Because vscode uses lsp to communicate with ts language service, so vscode can not do like `string literal rename` because ts do not support this feature. What I wonder is how IntelliJ can do this.

Comment: please provide files/code snippets plus steps to repeat the issues